# socket.io and express routing - how to setup

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, routes

I'm using:
*express: v4.16.1
socket.io: v2.0.3*

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

var index = require('./index.js');
app.use('/', index);

io.on('connection', function(socket){//connection stuff});
```

Now every use of expres router in **index.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/seo', function(req, res){//page stuff here});
```

disconnect my established socket.io connection... How to pin socket to express router?

Comment: What does "How to pin socket to express router?" mean?  A socket.io connection is independent of your routers.  If a browser is loading a new page, then there is no socket.io connection for that page yet (the page has get loaded and the JS in it has to run before it can have a socket.io connection).  If you're making an Ajax call from a browser, the socket.io connection is completely independent of that Ajax call routing.

Comment: "If a browser is loading a new page, then there is no socket.io connection for that page yet (the page has get loaded and the JS in it has to run before it can have a socket.io connection)." Is there any way to 'hold' a socket connection - so when user move from ww.mypage/one to ww.mypage/two connection is resume and data flow can be managed? User browser has socket js file in cache, domain is the same - the way I understand it, it should work without disconnecting the user. Even if disconnecting is a must, how to reconnect immediately when a page is loaded, do I need cookie or token?

Comment: If you're actually loading a new top level page, there is no way to keep a previous socket.io connection alive.  The browers closes and frees ALL resources from the prior page.  You could use frames and only load one frame while keeping others (not generally recommended).  The usual solution is to just let the socket.io drop and when the new page loads, it creates a new connection immediately.  You would use cookies to identify who it is that is reconnecting.